# How to link nodes in jupyter notebook with dask

Tags: dask, slurm, dask-distributed

So I am running on an HPC cluster using Slurm.  I have already obtained the nodes that I require (salloc --nodes=16 -t08:00:00 --qos=interactive).  Is there a way to run dask on a jupyter notebook that I open and have all of these nodes linked without having to wait for dask_jobqueue.SLURMCluster() to acquire all new nodes?

Also, is there a way to add the "--qos=interactive) for the SLURMCluster() routine?

Thanks

more info:
I access the hpc front-end through ssh.
Next I obtain nodes on the machine with:
    salloc --nodes=16 -t08:00:00 --qos=interactive
then I start a notebook:
   jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=9999
Next I ssh tunnel into the notebook:
    ssh -4 -t -L 9999:localhost:9999 lhovey@xxxx.lanl.gov ssh -t -L 9999:localhost:9999 yy-vv ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 nodename
Then I load the the jupyter notebook link into my browser and am currently in my notebook.

What I want to do is parallel processing on large image arrays. When I am on the notebook I just want to link it to the other 15 nodes I have already acquired so I do not have to run the SLURMCluster command from dask_jobqueue and wait to acquire all new nodes. the main reason is that I get nodes faster with the --qos=interactive and I am not able (I think) to use this option in dask

Comment: Sounds like an usage issue to dask-jobqueue . You should give more detail about your configuration, where/how your notebook is running and what exactly you want to be able to do.

Comment: I obtained nodes with: salloc --nodes=4 -t08:00:00 --qos=interactive.  Next I opened a jupyter notebook with: jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=9999, and then tunneled in to use the notebook on my browser.  What I want to do is parallel processing on large image arrays.  When I am on the notebook I just want to link it to the other 15 nodes I have already acquired so I do not have to run the SLURMCluster command from dask_jobqueue and wait to acquire all new nodes.  the main reason is that I get nodes faster with the --qos=interactive and I am not able (I think) to use this option in dask,

Comment: Please edit your question with your updates. Sounds like you might use [ssh](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/ssh.html#command-line) or the CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`dask-ssh`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/ssh.html#command-line) command was created exactly for your use-case. Please follow the instructions there.

Alternatively, you could view you situation as "bare metal", and take it upon yourself to decide which node will host your scheduler - execute `dask-scheduler` on this node - and execute `dask-worker` on the other nodes, giving the scheduler's address. The same scheduler address is the one you will need to give to your `Client` in the notebook.

Take careful note of the network interface being used by each executable, as in a HPC environment, you often have multiple choices.

Comment: ok when I try to "dask-ssh --hostfile hostfile.txt" I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/users/lhovey/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/deploy/old_ssh.py", line 57, in async_ssh
    banner_timeout=20,
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No authentication methods available
[ dask-ssh ] : SSH connection failed after 3 retries. Exiting.
My hostfile is a list of my nodedames separated with a carriage return.  I can do "ssh nodename" and it will go there.  I am not sure what I am missing...